# What happens if we try to extract a witness but it actually does not exist from a term of existential type?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, proof-theory

Given a term `t : ∀x.∃y.(¬(x = 0) ⇒ x = S(y))` in Martin-Lof's type theory, what's the value of `w(t(0))`, where `w` is the operator that extracts the witness of a term of existential type?

Comment: I think you mean $\neg(x=0)$.

Comment: Yes, Mark, thanks for pointing out that, fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any value. It depends upon which $t$ you are given. A term of type $\exists y.(\neg(0 = 0) \Rightarrow 0 = S(y))$ is a pair of an int $y$ and a function that takes a proof of $\neg(0=0)$ and gives you a proof of $0 = S(y)$. You can use a term of type $\neg(0 = 0)$ and type $0 = 0$ (from reflexivity) to derive a term of any type you want. This includes a term of type $0 = S(0)$, $0 = S(1)$, $\ldots$. So, you can make $y$ any integer you want.

Answer (score 10):

To demonstrate Mark's answer, consider the following proof `t` of your statement, written in Coq. In the proof we assume that a parameter `k` of type `nat` is given. We use `k` as the value of `y` in case `x = 0`:

```
Parameter k : nat.

Theorem t : forall x : nat, { y : nat | x <> 0 -> x = S y}.
Proof.
  induction x.
  exists k; tauto.
  induction x.
  exists 0; auto.
  destruct IHx as [z G].
  exists (S z).
  intro H.
  elim G; auto.
Defined.
```

We can prove that `t 0` is equal to `k`:

```
Theorem A: projT1 (t 0) = k.
Proof.
  auto.
Qed.
```

The `protT1` is there because `t 0` is not just a natural number, but actually a natural number *with* a proof that `0 <> 0 -> 0 = S y` and `projT1` throws away the proof.

The extracted Ocaml code for `t`, obtained with the command `Extraction k` is

```
(** val t : nat -> nat **)

let rec t = function
  | O -> k
  | S n0 -> (match n0 with
              | O -> O
              | S n1 -> S (t n0))
```

Again we can see `t 0` is equal to `k`, which was an aribtrarily assumed parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the example in Coq, Andrej, it clarifies more.